# Calculation of special natural numbers

Tags: integration, prime-factorization

As interested in factorization of integers, I had the idea to define the following
 natural numbers :

z(n) := [$\int_n^{n+1} x^x dx$]

My questions : 1) PARI can easily calculate z(n) numerically, but for large n it
                   takes quite a long time. Is there an efficient method to calculate
                   z(n) ? (The integral needs to be calculated with precision about
                   0.5)
                2) The largest prime I found is z(275). Can anyone find bigger ones ?
                3) z(79) is difficult to factor. I found the 34-digit prime-factor
                   1188 61814 33453 90012 05125 30694 68019. Can anyone factor the
                   remaining cofactor with 119 digits ?

Comment: The brackets mean integer part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear: do you have these values for $z(n)$?

$$
\begin{align}
z(9) =
& 2934896279 \\
z(10) =
& 81607544630 \\
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
z(25) = 
& 1427759269598032850533133531485164681 & \text{(37 digits)}\\
z(26) = 
& 101983795940249008487272274613469251169 & \text{(39 digits)}\\
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
z(79) = 
& 3269053961273978708012560763055091753206667067617118000189124825327 \\
& 0570988621006960668913100798229081854831546404994677634140270246629 \\
& 445048206444354751_c \\
& \text{(152 digits)} \\
\\
= 
& 1188618143345390012051253069468019_p \times \\
\\
& 2750297881263329571824046756719154740522462783913046919066948130351 \\
& 3561309565945466309498365930814024227177872638493829_c
\end{align}
$$

(since the above seems to match your factors and the following has been proven prime by APRCL, it would be very surprising for these to be different values)

$$
\begin{align}
z(275) = 
& 7404191871659104208983292411749579036693797273275810189154445217936 \\
& 8467539785423380425089304114782854116153515916169989356742884450414 \\
& 4559801172499309126587825244523783663393812553680157021618805963694 \\
& 7798501699634139078133395690188856029933501844025752694479861667486 \\
& 1660251950422497773626507007074206879521555579938034101830345982591 \\
& 1344230636448033427715283474786261266344944699639988373912291606495 \\
& 8280143851113390552378895598210161435974719562757471009957868468703 \\
& 1477834800616139218451950443738032002169647675171121492023021793178 \\
& 0500040547536539078580164652020723213547855727859376965297953795958 \\
& 2303663666173993184294926653400974771731334504129910369425994666844 \\
& 801_p \\
& \text{(673 digits)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the best suggestion I can make is to calculate $z(n)$ with a precision of at least $2 \lceil (n + 1) \log_k{(n + 1)} \rceil$, with PARI/GP preferring to use $k = 10$.  For $n = 275$ that means using `default(realprecision, 1348)`, which allows `intnum(x = 275, 276, x^x)` to calculate, after considerable time, an integer part of 2236 bits and a fractional part of 2244 bits.  The fractional bits appear to be uniformly distributed (slightly biased toward $0$).  The integer bits appear to be non-uniformly distributed (biased toward $1$).

It seems reasonable to expect the upper half of the significant digits to be correct, but that might not be justified.

---

$z(79)$ is tough to factor.  It seems that the numbers adjacent to its factors tend to involve very large primes, so there are no conveniently small subgroups to work in.  Since $x^x$ behaves so wildly, $z(n)$ can probably be expected to produce a lot of "unstructured" composites.