# Expected error due to the tablemakers' dilemma

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, algorithms, numerical-methods

*[note: to me, this does not seem like a question for m.se, but on mathoverflow it has been retroactively closed, with very little indication of why or what might be corrected... and waiting for responses there has not advanced the problem]*

EDIT: the MO URL is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158370/expected-error-due-to-the-tablemakers-dilemma

Consider the integer function $z(n)$ defined in *[Calculation of special natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576982/calculation-of-special-natural-numbers)*:

$$
z(n) := \Bigg\lfloor \int_n^{n+1} x^x dx \Bigg\rfloor
$$

For all $n \ge 0$, this has a definite integer value.  What we would like to do is to identify a *known* integer with this value.  However, $x^x$ represents the composition of two transcendental functions, $e^{x \log{x}}$, and the integral represents an operation over infinitely many points of the function.  Numerical approximation of transcendental functions may require arbitrarily high precision *at every point*; for each point it is difficult to determine in advance what precision will be needed to ensure the truncated binary value will be accurate in its least significant bits (for example, it might be necessary to distinguish a string of arbitrarily many $1$ bits from a truncated string of $0$ bits).  That is the **tablemakers' dilemma**.

*[in particular, Wolfram's online calculator fails to distinguish a string of $\textit 0$s from a string of $\textit 0$s containing a $\textit 1$]*

What we can actually produce is $\hat z(n)$, an approximation by some finite method to some finite precision of $z(n)$, which we hope is accurate in sufficiently many of its most significant bits to determine the result of the floor function.  In the linked post, $\hat z(n)$ is calculated by PARI/GP.

- Under what conditions should we consider $\hat z(n)$ *incorrect* or *undefined*?
- What should one expect to be the magnitude of the error in approximating the integral?
- What methods should one use for the approximation, to attain high confidence that the result has sufficient accuracy to be manipulated as an integer?
- *As calculated by PARI/GP*, $\hat z(275)$ is odd, and a *prime*.  Might $z(275)$ be *even*?

*[more precise calculation has agreement at the units bit, but I have no error bounds and differentiating **this** function only makes it more complicated]*

Comment: To obtain full confidence, one can use interval arithmetic with directed (outward) rounding. This (numerically and automatically) produces rigorous error bounds. (Of course, it might happen that this gives as the answer an interval which contains more than one integer, so that $z(x)$ still is unknown; then one can try rerunning the computation with higher precision.)